# Debugging .NET Code running in a specific pod replica into a AKS/Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0, remote-debugging

I am looking for a solution to debug .NET 6 code (F#) running in AKS clusters with Visual Studio Code. I have tried Bridge to Kubernetes, but it doesn't allow (as far as I know) attaching to a running specific replica pod when in a deployment. It doesn't attach to a running process, rather starts one new locally and diverts traffic to it. This is not what I am looking for; I want to attach to an already running process in AKS/K8s (remote-debugging).

I have found other potential ways (https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Attaching-to-remote-processes) or [telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/), however couldn't find a clear tutorial for .NET Code, AKS or Kubernetes and VS Code.

Is there a clear example of either

- (If possible) direct Bridge to Kubernetes to attach to a specific existing replica POD?
- Use another way to achieve the same result?

I am happy to use kubernetes port forwarding or use Visual Studio 2022 instead of Visual Studio Code, if this makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your `kube-config` file that points correctly to your cluster. You can do so for AKS as follows:

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group k8s-demo-ss --name k8s-demo-cluster-ss --file kubeconfig-ss
```

Then you can simply attach to your running pods in the cluster with:

```
kubectl exec -ti <pod>/<container> -n <namespace> bash
```

This will open up `bash` in your container allowing you to debug it.

Comment: How does this allow me to attach Visual Studio Code debugger to the running process in the container?

Comment: Not sure about VS Code but Visual Studio can be attached with AKS. Perhaps [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-kubernetes?view=vs-2022) will help.

Comment: Also, having `kubeconfig` will allow you to setup a proxy to your cluster which will allow you to communicate with your cluster. I'm unsure you will be able to attach a remote process in your cluster to your local debugger in VS Code.

Comment: Also, you can use `ephemeral debug containers` to be able to debug your applications by starting an ephemeral container in your pod. More information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/).